# Various modes of convergence of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Let $\lbrace X_n \rbrace_n$ be a sequence of independent random variables such that $$P(\{X_n = \pm 1 \}) = \frac{1}{n}$$ $$P(\{X_n = 0 \}) = 1 - \frac{2}{n}$$ Is the sequence convergent:

$1$) almost everywhere ?

$2$) in probability ?

$3$) in distribution ?

$4$) in $L^p$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $p\geqslant 1$, we have $\lVert X_n\rVert_p^p=2/n$, hence $X_n\to 0$ in $\mathbb L^p$. Since (in general) convergence in $\mathbb L^1$ implies convergences in probability, which implies in turn convergence in distribution, we can answer questions  2), 3) and 4). Note that for these question, we did not use independence.

Question 1) can be solved using the Borel-Cantelli's lemma.

Comment: Davide Giraudo, can you show also the point $1)$ ?

Comment: Yes, I can. But I let you try first.

Comment: Ok, so I'll try

Comment: @DavideGiraudo, I like $+1$! Should $\lVert X_n\rVert_p^p\le2/n$ since, for odd $p$, $\lVert X_n\rVert_p^p{}={}0$?

Comment: @ki3i Note that $|X_n|=1$ with probability $2/n$n and $0$ with probability $1-2/n$ (recall that the $p$-norm contains the $p$-th power of the absolute value).

Comment: @DavideGiraudo, Of course, Thanks.